# Received "Failed to execute goal on project" in Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm trying to execute the test cases in Maven, but am getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project goblin-AOS-tests: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.groupon.itqa.goblin.goblin-tests:goblin-AOS-tests:jar:2.0.0-BETA-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.groupon.itqa.goblin.goblin-core:goblin-webdriver:jar:2.0.11-BETA (compile), com.groupon.itqa.goblin.goblin-core:goblin-utils:jar:2.0.11-BETA (compile), com.groupon.itqa.goblin.goblin-gapi:utils:jar:1.0.0-BETA (compile), org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.3 (compile), org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.3 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.groupon.itqa.goblin.goblin-gapi:utils:jar:1.0.0-BETA: Could not find artifact com.groupon.itqa.goblin:goblin-gapi:pom:1.0.0-BETA-SNAPSHOT in default (http://nexus-app1-dev.snc1/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Check if you have those artifacts in your nexus repository. If yes fix the access to this nexus repository. Correctly configured in your settings.xml file?

Comment: Just upload this dependency "com.groupon.itqa.goblin:goblin-gapi:pom:1.0.0-BETA-SNAPSHOT" into your nexus repository..It should work after..

Comment: Great! I did checked the both files and I found some changes in it. I have fixed it. Thanks all! :)